# How do you multiply two conditional probabilities?

Tags: probability

I have to multiply this:

$P(a|b,c)·P(b|c)$

How do you multiply those two expressions?

It seems that $P(a|b,c)·P(b|c) = P(a,b|c)$ but I don't know how to obtain that expression multiplying the two previous conditional probabilities.

Comment: Intuitively you could compare this with P(a|b)P(b) = P(a,b)

Comment: Are you asking about the arithmetic as in @StatsStudent 's answer? Or are you asking "what the *nomenclature* of the product of these two probabilities?"

Comment: The nomenglature.

Comment: Note, that this is only true so long as $P(c)>0$ and $P(bc)>0$.

Comment: @VansFannel Since you are a new user, please be sure to accept the answer that helped you most by clicking the left check mark.  Accepts help encourage users to provide answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Those two expressions simply mean:

(the Probability of event $a$ given the events $b$ and $c$) $\times$ (the Probability of event $b$ given event $c$).

The two terms are probabilities which are scalar values between the 0 and 1 (including 0 and 1).  So you simply multiply the two values together as you would any two numbers.  So for example, if the probability of $a$, given $b$ and $c$ were 0.40 and the probability of $b$ given $c$ where .70, then:

$P(a|b,c)·P(b|c)=0.40\times0.70=0.28$

**UPDATED BASED ON YOUR EDITED QUESTION:**

The proof is straight-forward and is based on three applications of the the definition of conditional probability, which states that if $D$ and $E$ are two events in space $S$, and $P(E)>0$, then the conditional probability of $D$ given $E$, written by $P(D|E)$ is $\frac{P(DE)}{P(E)}$

\begin{eqnarray*}
P(a|bc)P(b|c) & = & P(a|bc)\frac{P(bc)}{P(c)}\\
 & = & \frac{P(abc)}{P(bc)}\frac{P(bc)}{P(c)}\\
 & = & \frac{P(abc)}{P(c)}\\
 & = & \frac{P[(ab)c]}{P(c)}\\
 & = & P(ab|c)
\end{eqnarray*}

So, in all, we have:

\begin{eqnarray*}
P(a|bc)P(b|c) & = & P(ab|c)
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know the probabilities $P(a|b,c)$ or $P(b|c)$ themselves, you can try to reformulate them in terms of probabilities that you do know. The [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule_(probability)), or [Baye's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) would be useful for doing so. For example, by the chain rule:
$$
P(a,b,c) = P(a|b,c) P(b|c) P(c)
$$
which would imply:
$$
P(a|b,c) P(b|c) = \frac{P(a,b,c)}{P(c)}
$$
so if you had the probabilities $P(a,b,c)$ and $P(c)$, you would be able to calculate the product of $P(a|b,c)$ and $P(b|c)$.

Comment: I have updated my question with more details. Sorry to do it so late. I want to know the expression, not the value, resulting of multiplying the two conditional probabilities.